# How to setup a simple Unit Test with Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, mocking

I'm new to Moq and not quite sure why this won't run.

**Repository Interface**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<string> list();
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IService
{
    IEnumerable<string> AllItems();
}
```

**Service Class**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Service : IService
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> AllItems()
    {
        return _repository.list();
    }
}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MoqTest;
using MoqTest.Controllers;
using Moq;
using MoqTest.Models;

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    private Mock<IRepository> _mockRepository;
    private IService _service;

    [TestMethod]
    public void my_test()
    {
        //Arrange.
        List<string> theList = new List<string>();
        theList.Add("test3");
        theList.Add("test1");
        theList.Add("test2");

        _mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();

        //The line below returns a null reference...
        _mockRepository.Setup(s => s.list()).Returns(theList);
        _service = new Service(_mockRepository.Object);

        //Act.
        var myList = _service.AllItems();
        Assert.IsNotNull(myList, "myList is null.");

        //Assert.
        Assert.AreEqual(3, myList.Count());
    }
}
```

I wanted to set this up as a very simple unit test.  It is failing on the _mockRepository.Setup call. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT -

**Error Message**

```
Test method Tests.my_test threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
Moq.MethodCall.SetFileInfo()
Moq.MethodCall..ctor(Mock mock, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
Moq.MethodCallReturn..ctor(Mock mock, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
ctor(Mock mock, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
b__11()
Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
TResult](Mock mock, Expression`1 expression)
Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
Tests.my_test() in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MoqTest\MoqTest.Tests\Controllers\Tests.cs: line 28
```

Comment: Everything looks right, could you post the exception stack so we can try to figure out what's going on?

Comment: OK, added the error message and stack trace from the test result page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrelated to the problem you are having, you can move the mock initialization out into a common `TestInitialize` method that would get run before every test. This way you can keep the common init code in one place and make your tests much smaller and more readable.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit() {
    //Arrange.
    List<string> theList = new List<string>();
    theList.Add("test3");
    theList.Add("test1");
    theList.Add("test2");

    _mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();

    //The line below returns a null reference...
    _mockRepository.Setup(s => s.list()).Returns(theList);
    _service = new Service(_mockRepository.Object);
}

[TestMethod]
public void my_test()
{
    //Act.
    var myList = _service.AllItems();
    Assert.IsNotNull(myList, "myList is null.");

    //Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(3, myList.Count());
}
```

I've just run this test exactly as posted and it worked for me. I am using Moq v4.0 beta There was a specific bug fix in this release that I needed, otherwise 3.1.4(the latest stable release) has been rock solid for me.

Comment: Yep, that was my plan. I actually had it setup this way, but moved it all into the one test function to simplify before posting. (and make sure I wasn't calling something incorrectly)