# Understanding Mock Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

am trying to understand using Mock unit testing and i started with MOQ . this question can be answered in General as well.

Am just trying to reuse the code given in [How to setup a simple Unit Test with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114948/how-to-setup-a-simple-unit-test-with-moq?rq=1)

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit() {
    //Arrange.
    List<string> theList = new List<string>();
    theList.Add("test3");
    theList.Add("test1");
    theList.Add("test2");

    _mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();

    //The line below returns a null reference...
    _mockRepository.Setup(s => s.list()).Returns(theList);
    _service = new Service(_mockRepository.Object);
}

[TestMethod]
public void my_test()
{
    //Act.
    var myList = _service.AllItems();
    Assert.IsNotNull(myList, "myList is null.");

    //Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(3, myList.Count());
}
```

Here is my question

1 . In testInitialize we are setting theList count to 3(string) and we are returning the same using MOQ and in the below line we are going to get the same

```
var myList = _service.AllItems(); //Which we know will return 3
```

So what we are testing here ?

2 . what are the possible scenarios where the Unit Testing fails ? yes we can give wrong values as 4 and fail the test. But in realtime i dont see any possiblity of failing ?

i guess am little backward in understanding these concepts. I do understand the code but am trying to get the insights !! Hope somebody can help me !

Answer (score 3):

The system under test (SUT) in your example is the Service class. Naturally, the field _service uses the true implementation and not a mock. The method tested here is AllItems, do not confuse with the list() method of IRepository. This latter interface is a dependency of your SUT Service therefore it is mocked and passed to the Service class via constructor. I think you are confused by the fact that AllItems method seems to only return the call from list() method of its dependency IRepository. Hence, there is not a lot of logic involved there. Maybe, reconsider this example and add more expected logic for the AllItems method. For example you may assert that the AllItems returns the same elements provided by the list() method but reordered.

Comment: The service is mocked and the list will be returned as  i mentioned in the question 1

Comment: No, only the repository is mocked. The service, which is the SUT, uses the *real* implementation. To answer you question 1) the response is your are testing "that the list returned by AllItems returns as much as elements as the list returned by the IRepository".
For the insights, you should see UnitTests as contracts that the SUT should verify. What I meant by my answer above, is that your SUT lacks of logic for being a good example of unit test, add more complexity of the logic brought by AllItems on the given context. The given context being the list returned by the Mock<IRepository>.

Comment: Can you share any links where i can take it from here !!

Comment: I think you can have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690135/using-moq-and-tdd-where-to-start).
On this subject, I liked this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Test-Driven-Development-Applications/dp/047064320X)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you with this one.

1.) As for this one, your basically testing he count. Sometimes in a collection, the data accumulates so it doesn't necessarily mean that each time you exectue the code is always 3. The next time you run, it adds 3 so it becomes 6 then 9 and so on.

2.) For unit testing, there are a lot of ways to fail like wrong computations, arithmetic overflow errors and such. [Here's](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) a good article.

Answer (score 0):

1. The test is supposed to verify that the Service talks to its Repository correctly. We do this by setting up the mock Repository to return a canned answer that is easy to verify. However, with the test as it is now :

   - Service could perfectly return any list of 3 made-up strings without communicating with the Repository and *the test would still pass*. **Suggestion** : use `Verify()` on the mock to check that `list()` was really called.
   - 3 is basically a magic number here. Changes to `theList` could put that number out of sync and break the test. **Suggestion** : use `theList.Count` instead of 3. Better : instead of checking the number of elements in the list, verify that `AllItems()` returns exactly what was passed to it by the Repository. You can use a `CollectionAssert` for that.

   This means getting `theList` and `_mockRepository` out of `TestInit()` to make them accessible in a wider scope or directly inside the `TestMethod`, which is probably better anyways (not much use having a `TestInitialize` here).
2. The test would fail if the Service somehow stopped talking to its Repository, if it stopped returning exactly what the Repository gives it, or if the Repository's contract changed. More importantly, it *wouldn't fail* if there was a bug in the real implementation for IRepository - testing small units allows you to point your finger at the exact object that is failing and not its neighbors.